# What are the interest of returning DictRow instead of simple dictionary in Psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

Psycopg2 with a `DictCursor` return `DictRow` and not `dict` object.

I'm still struggling to see what advantages does `DictRow` give instead of converting to simple dict object.

The documentation on it is pretty slim [link](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

From the linked [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor):

> The records still support indexing as the original tuple:
>
> ```
> >>> rec[2]  
> "abc'def"`
> ```

So `DictRow` supports both indexing into a row tuple (when you give it an `int` or a `slice`) and by-column-name access.